# How to zgrep a specific key:value from .json.gz file

Tags: json, grep, gzip, zgrep

I have a bunch of logs in multiples `.json.gz` files.
I can easily get a specific string with:

```
zgrep "Search This String" *
```

But now I need to find a specific value inside a key/attribute.
I tried the following code to get a email domain from `sender` key/attribute.

```
zgrep -o '"message.sender":"[^"]*@mypattern[^"]*"' *
```

Unfortunatelly it doesn't work.

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can usually use grep's `-A` or `-C` to get the context lines around or after what you want.   If you're trying to get that pattern and one line before and after, you can use `-C1`.  etc.